# How can i change the size of the treeView1 and keep it docked to the left?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a User Control i created and the size of the User Control designer i set it to:

Width 808 Height 610

On the designer i added a panel the size of the panel is:

Width 808 Height 610

Then i added a splitter on the panel:

Width 3 Height 588

On that the left side i have a treeView on the right size a listView
The treeView size is:

Width 256 Height 588

The listView size is:

Width 549 Height 588

I went to this size project and downloaded the resource code and in the resource code it's a form project windows forms and i created a Class Library project with a User Control.

[Source Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2316/Windows-Explorer-in-C?fid=3925&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx)

In this windows forms the treeView size is 256,528
And the listView size is 533,528

I can't change on my project on my User Control the treeView size the Height to 528 same for the listView can't change it to 528.
If i change it as it is now it will return automatic to the size 588
If i make them not to be docked to the right or left and change the size right after changing the size if i dock them back the szie is fixed to 588

All i want is to have the same sizes the same designer like in the windows forms project.
All the controls sizes are the same except the treeView and the listView.

This is a screenshot of my User Control designer:

[image: User Control]

If it will help i have my User Control designer on pastebin.com

[image: My User Control Designer]

This is the source project the windows forms project designer screenshot:

[image: The original source windows forms designer]

You can see on the original designer from the windows forms that there is a menu above the treeView File Help

I have this menu too but since my treeView and listView sizes are not the same they cover this menu.

Comment: I don't understand how they docked it on the size of Height 528 and i when docking it's size is 588. Why in my case it's 588 ? I never changed the treeView Height to 588. Why when i'm docking it's not 528 ?

Comment: @Piranha: Please use actual, non-profane words here. Not everyone enjoys reading obscenities. This is a professional technical site. Please behave that way here.

Comment: Edited not so good but enough to see where is the problem. In the original the source in the site the windows forms designer the treeView size Height is 528 and you see the menu File Home....In my User Control the treeView Height is 588 and you don't see the menu File Help....That's what i can't change in my User Control the Height size of the treeView and listView from 588 to 528.

Comment: If each pane of the Splitter contains only one control shouldn't you dock them to Fill? Also: Are there perhaps any Margins? Also : __Docking will fill the docked side..__ So if you Dock Left the Height will be the height of the container.

Comment: TaW on the original windows forms the treeView is docked to the left and the margins are 3,3,3,3 and the listView is docked Fill and margin 3,3,3,3 same settings on my User Control. I will keep checking maybe i'm missing something but so far everything is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I added you UserControl Designer Code.
The MainMenu object you are using is not working for me at all (btw. It's deprecated)

Instead I added a **MenuStrip** and it worked like expected:

[image: Form Screenshot]

It looks exactly the same in the UserControl in the Designer